# How can you hash a set of points represented as Doubles in Java?

Tags: java, hash, coordinates, hashtable

let me explain my goal.

I'm trying to 1.) Read in a set of points (like a cartesian plan) user input, and count how many times each point
occurs in the input. 2.)Then to print out each unique point along with the number of times it occurs in the input. X and Y points are to be represented as doubles. This, since I am practicing Hash tables, is to be done with a hash table. 3.) I also want to count the number of comparisons that are made while hashing the points which I tried by overriding the equals method. The thing is I, I know I'm not supposed to call hash code because it is automatically called by the Hash table API, but I'm not sure what to put. so I did and it's wrong. I'm stuck. Here is my code so far:

MAIN CLASS:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

boolean e = true;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = "";
int yesOrNo = 3;
String x = "";
String y = "";

Hashtable<Integer, Point> PointTable = new Hashtable<Integer, Point>();

while(e){
  System.out.println("Please enter a point to add to hash table.");
  userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
  x = userInput.substring(0,3);
  y = userInput.substring(4,7);
  Point a = new Point(new Double(x), new Double(y));
  PointTable.put(a.hashCode(), a); 
  System.out.println("Enter another point? 0 to quit. anything else to continue");
  yesOrNo = keyboard.nextInt();
  if(yesOrNo == 0){
    break;
  }
  keyboard.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(Point.count);
System.out.println(PointTable.values());
}
```

}

POINT CLASS:

```
 public class Point{

 private Double x, y;
 public static int count;

 public Point(Double x, Double y){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
 }
 public Double getX(){
   return x;
 }
 public Double getY(){
   return y;
 }
 public int getCount(){
     return count; 
    }
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
   count++;
   if (this == o)
     return true;

   if (!(o instanceof Point))
     return false;

   Point otherPoint = (Point) o;
   return otherPoint.x == x && otherPoint.y == y;
 }
 @Override
 public int hashCode(){
   int hash = 7;
   hash = 71 * hash + this.x.intValue();
   hash = 71 * hash + this.y.intValue();
   return hash;
 }
}
```

And here is an example of what I want the output to be:

```
 (3.0,2.0): 4
 (1.0,4.0): 1
 (5.0,7.0): 1
 (1.0,3.0): 1
 (4.0,5.0): 1
 (1.0,2.0): 2
 Number of comparisons = 8
```

Thank you.

Comment: `if (this == o)` this code in your `equals` method will try to compare the objectIDs of the 2 `Point` objects. This will ALWAYS return false. Your `equals` method should compare the x and y variables instead. Ex: `if(this.x == o.getX() && this.y == o.getY())`

Comment: @CalvinP., not sure what you're talking about. Starting an equals implementation with `this == o` is pretty standard. What's more concerning however, is the use of `==` between `Doubles`. You either want to change to `double` or you probably want to do `x.equals(otherPoint.x) && y.equals(otherPoint.y)`.

Comment: @aioobe I realize now that I confused the primitive type `double` with the `Double` object type (which is what op is using), but `this == o` merely checks if the object references are the same. Since he creates a new `Point` object for each line of input, the new object is not a reference to an object that was previously created. He needs to compare values in this case, not just references.

Comment: Well, of all problems in this code, you chose to point at an optimization issue? Doing `this == o` is completely harmless. In fact all auto-generated `equals` methods I've seen includes this check.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you store the point in the Hashtable? Two equal points will have the same hashcode and override each other in the hashtable. What you want to store is the number of times a point occurs.

So instead of saving the point for a hashcode:

```
Hashtable<Integer, Point> PointTable = new Hashtable<Integer, Point>();
```

save a number for a point:

```
Hashtable<Point, Integer> pointTable = new Hashtable<Point, Integer>();
```

then get the number for the point, increment it and store it back to the hashtable (if it was null, insert 1)

Comment: Ok I get what your saying. Can you give me an example of what that would look like? I'm confused about getting the number and incrementing it

Comment: When you created the point a, you have to check whether it is in the hashtable: `Integer count = pointTable.get(a);` If count is null, put a and the value 1 into the pointtable, if not, put count+1 into the table

Comment: Or, `if (!pointTable.containsKey(a)) { pointTable.put(a, 0); } pointTable.put(a, pointTable.get(a) + 1);` (There's a convenience method for that in Java 8 called [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).)

Comment: I did what you said here aiobe but when i try to print the pointable values it says that they are all 1. For example 1.0 1.0, 1.0 1.0 for input gives me [1,1] where as I'm trying to see how many times each point appears. Am i missing something?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Would be useful to post your updated code